# how to display data with javascript [object]

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

Please Help Me data does not appear in the div
result and display [object] how to fix it?

```
 <div id="result">
 </div>
 <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    var html = 'Sedang memproses data';
    $('#result').html(html);
    $('#result').css('background','none');
    $.getJSON( "get.php?nopel=<?php echo $idp;?>", function(data) {
      if(data) {
          html = '<h2>Berikut Tagihan Listrik Anda</h2><table>';
          $.each(data,function(x,y){
              html += '<tr><td>'+x.replace('_','/')+'</td><td>'+y+'</td>';
          });
          html += '</table>';
          $('#result').html(html);
      }
      else {
           $('#result').html('Tidak ada data');
      }
    });
   });
</script>
```

with json data like this, how to invite it to JavaScript

```
{
 "status": "success",
  "data": [
{
  "Info": "A",
  "hasil": "AA"
},
{
  "Info": "B",
  "hasil": "BB"
}
 ]
}
```

console.log (data)
[image]

Comment: change `$.each(data, ...` to `$.each(data.data, ...`

Comment: sounds like you want `$.each(data.data` instead of `$.each(data`, since the response has a `data`key holding an array. As a side, funny note, I've never ever seen someone saying that he needs to "invite" json data to javascript. That's weird.

Comment: can give an example with my code above @MattEllen

Comment: Amazingly similar question to one I [remember seeing yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56891313/how-to-display-data-with-javascript)

Comment: @MedicalClinic that is in your code above. where you write `$.each(data, function(x,y){` change `data` to `data.data`

Comment: @freefaller that's a very nice catch, indeed.

Comment: I have done $ .each (data.data, function (x, y)
data does not appear @MattEllen

Comment: @MedicalClinic please `console.log(data);` and post it above, so that we can do further work.

Comment: I would assume then that you have no data.

Comment: @briosheje, after I tried doing console.log (data); data appears, but he doesn't appear in the div, there might be a mistake in my JavaScript

Comment: thnks @freefaller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, please don't use [multiple accounts](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10735580/doctor-junior) to ask the [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56891313/how-to-display-data-with-javascript).

There are two main issues with your code...

- As pointed out in comments by multiple people, if you want the `data`property in your `data` json object, then you need to use `data.data` instead of `data`
- The [`$.each`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) function passes two parameters (index and value), but it appears that you think that it's passing the two properties of the object.

The below has the two changes, where you can see I've changed `function(x,y)` to `function(i,v)` where `v` is the object.  I'm then using `v.Info` and `v.hasil`...

```js
var data = 
{
 "status": "success",
  "data": [
    {
      "Info": "A",
      "hasil": "AA"
    },
    {
      "Info": "B",
      "hasil": "BB"
    }
 ]
}

$(function(){
  var html = 'Sedang memproses data';
  $('#result').html(html);
  $('#result').css('background','none');
  //$.getJSON( "get.php?nopel=<?php echo $idp;?>", function(data) {
    if(data) {
        html = '<h2>Berikut Tagihan Listrik Anda</h2><table>';
        $.each(data.data,function(i,v){
            html += '<tr><td>'+v.Info.replace('_','/')+'</td><td>'+v.hasil+'</td>';
        });
        html += '</table>';
        $('#result').html(html);
    }
    else {
         $('#result').html('Tidak ada data');
    }
  //});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="result">
</div>
```